# CDI: get manually instance of bean of class which is declared with generics

Tags: java, generics, cdi

This is the way how I get manually instance of cdi bean:

```
Bean<?> bean = (Bean<?>)beanManager.resolve(beanManager.getBeans(Foo.class));
Foo foo=(Foo) beanManager.getReference(bean, bean.getBeanClass(), beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean));
```

if I declare Foo class this way:

```
@Dependent
public class Foo{
   ...
}
```

everything works. However, if I declare class Foo this way

```
@Dependent
public class Foo<T>{
   ...
}
```

cdi container can't create cdi bean. How can I get manually cdi bean of class declared with generics (Foo)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably [`javax.enterprise.util.TypeLiteral`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/util/TypeLiteral.html).
It is a utility class allowing you to specify a (bean) type along with the type variable. It then allows to retrieve the raw type as well as the actual type parameter inside. Here is a code snippet:

```
// define the type you want
TypeLiteral<Foo<Bar>> typeLiteral = new TypeLiteral<Foo<Bar>>() {};

// now search for beans; note that getBeans allows to specify Annotations as well!
Set<Bean<?>> beans = beanManager.getBeans(typeLiteral.getType());

// and apply resolution - you should get the one you want here
Bean<?> bean = beanManager.resolve(beans);
```

Comment: @Pavel does it work for you? If not, what's the problem? I could help even further, just need to see, how things stand :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't get notification about your answer.

Comment: Seems you have a mistake. With rawType it doesn't work. This way works `Set<Bean<?>> beans = beanManager.getBeans(typeLiteral.getType());`

Comment: @Pavel_K yes, you are right, an oversight from me. I edited the answer.